# SQL: Convert String of MMMDD to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a nvarchar(5) column of data that is formatted MMMDD (for example, OCT26). With my select statement, I'd like to convert it to a datetime data type with the current year, and then save that datetime value as an alias, say, UsefulDate. So something like 10-26-2012.

Something like: SELECT (whatever SQL gets the job done) AS UsefulDate

The exact formatting doesn't matter; I just need to be able to compare two dates together with greater than and less than operators. Also, sometimes the column will be blank. In that case, I'd like to set the alias to blank as well. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will need to provide a year - you can't parse a month and day to a valid `DATETIME` alone.

Comment: @Oded: OP specified the current year in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert varchar fields in format MMMDD to date with current year with :

```
select convert(datetime,'OCT26'+','+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar),107)
```

So your query would be something like :

```
select convert(datetime,case varcharDate when '' then null else varcharDate end +
               ','+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar),107) as UsefulDate 
from table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, but it seems to be throwing an error when it hits a blank value: 

"The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE WHEN ISDATE(mmmdd+' '+right(year(getdate()),4)) = 1
            THEN CAST(mmmdd+' '+right(year(getdate()),4) as datetime)
            END UsefulDate, *
  from tbl
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, however, when it hits a blank value, it defaults to 2012-01-01. Is there a way to keep those values blank?

Comment: @Brent Updated answer for blanks

Comment: for some reason it's still defaulting to 2012-01-01. That's really cool how you can use a case statement with SQL though. I never knew you could do that.